# total sum mat-checked Array variable

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using mat-checked to get a total sum from an Array. In this case, if the number of items in my array is 4, everything works fine. But the problem is that the quantity is variable so I get an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'isChecked' of undefined

How can I make the sum always work independent of the amount of items in my Array?

So my code goes like this:

component.ts

```
get total(): number {
    return (this.paquete.extras2[0].isChecked ? this.paquete.extras2[0].costo : 0) * this.numeroPersonas +
    (this.paquete.extras2[1].isChecked ? this.paquete.extras2[1].costo : 0) * this.numeroPersonas +
    (this.paquete.extras2[2].isChecked ? this.paquete.extras2[2].costo : 0) * this.numeroPersonas +
    (this.paquete.extras2[3].isChecked ? this.paquete.extras2[3].costo : 0) * this.numeroPersonas +
    this.subtotal;
  }
```

component.html

```
<div *ngFor="let extra of paquete.extras2">
  <div class="d-flex justify-content-between" [ngClass]="{ 'textExtra': !extra.isChecked}">
  <mat-checkbox class="nmb" [(ngModel)]="extra.isChecked">
  <span>
  {{extra.nombre}}: {{ extra.costo | currency: '$ ' : 'symbol' : '1.0' }}/persona x {{numeroPersonas}}
  </span>
  </mat-checkbox>
  <span class="myWhiteSpace ml-4 ">{{ extra.costo * numeroPersonas | currency: '$ ' : 'symbol' : '1.0' }}</span>
  </div>
  <hr class="my-2">
</div>

<span>{{total | currency: '$ ' : 'symbol' : '1.0' }}</span>
```

Comment: Use a loop which runs till the length of the array...

Answer (score 0):

Once try this

`get total():number{ 
let sum =0;
return this.paquete.extras2.filter(e=>e['isChecked'] ===true)).reduce((sum, x) => sum +(x['costo']*this.numeroPersonas) || 0), 0);`